# Subir BD a un servidor Linux - MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

Tengo mi BD en MySQL y de manera local lo trabajo en Windows, pero cuando quiero trabajarlo de manera remota tengo que subir mi BD a un servidor Linux y lo hago mediante el "Putty", lo que hago es generar el Script desde el Workbench que tengo en Windows, copiar y pegar el Script en el Putty (Linux) pero cuando hay regular data, demora en subir el BackUp al servidor, hay alguna manera de subir esto más rápido? o es la única manera?

Comment: Usar el mismo workbench

Comment: podes configurar la base remota y copiar de una base a la otra, si el puerto de mysql no está abierto en el servidor remoto y dado que tenes acceso por putty seguramente puedas hacer un tunel ssh. Hay algunas pistas de como hacerlo aqui https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314701/258399

Comment: @aloMalbarez probaré eso, gracias por el dato!!

Comment: si lo resolves ponelo como respuesta y menciona workbench en el título (yo uso heidisql para tunelear, de ahí que no pueda dar un ejemplo concreto para workbench)